# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: at UserType.nullSafeSet()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, usertype

I have custom `enum` values to be persisted in DB. To do that I have implemented [StringValuedEnum](https://github.com/wwadge/ThrowayFinal/blob/master/model/src/main/java/com/go/demo/util/StringValuedEnum.java), [StringValuedEnumType](https://github.com/wwadge/ThrowayFinal/blob/master/model/src/main/java/com/go/demo/util/StringValuedEnumType.java) and [StingValuedEnumReflect](https://github.com/wwadge/ThrowayFinal/blob/master/model/src/main/java/com/go/demo/util/StringValuedEnumReflect.java) and my `enum` implements `StringValuedEnum`.

When I run my code with manually managed JPA everything works just fine and my enum values are persisted in DB. But as soon as I run the application with a container managed JPA (Wildfly 8.2), I get the following error upon flushing the entity manager:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: yyy.xxx.util.StringValuedEnumType.nullSafeSet(Ljava/sql/PreparedStatement;Ljava/lang/Object;ILorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;)V
at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:158) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1335) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.flush(AbstractEntityManager.java:457) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
at zzz.ejb.facades.EntityManagerFacade.createObject(EntityManagerFacade.java:2024) [zzz-ejb.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:407)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83) [wildfly-weld-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.processInvocation(NonPooledEJBComponentInstanceAssociatingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:251) [wildfly-ejb3-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
```

It looks like the issue is in pooling (there is non-pooled EJB component as it is shown in the stack trace).

The strange is that I cannot debug it to understand the issue: the debugger doesn't stop on any breakpoint put inside the method, nor the `System.out.println()` works.

**Questions**:

- What is the difference between manually and container managed JPAs that causes this difference in persisting custom types?
- How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my solution(s) here so that others could see and maybe use too, but if the exact answer would be provided, that would be highly appreciated.

I solved my issue just by annotating my entity column with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` so that the enum name is being persisted. That was ok for my enum... But in case if the enum has some fields and you want to persist a field's value, then you can do the following in your entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
public class EntityClass {

    // columns

    @Transient
    private EnumClass enumObj;

    @Column(name = "ENUM_COL_NAME")
    private String enumColField;

    // ......................

    @PostLoad
    void fillTransient() {
        enumObj = EnumClass.fromValue(enumColField);
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    void fillPersistent() {
        if (enumObj != null) {
            enumColField = enumObj.getField();
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, and even if your enum has multiple fields and you want to persist them separately in DB then you can have as many columns as many you want, fill those columns and retrieve them in the provided way.

Answer (score 5):

The signature for the UserType methods nullSafeSet and nullSafeGet was changed from Hibernate 3 to hibernate 4. What you need to do is to update those methods in your custom user types.

Change it from this:

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
```

to this:

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
```

As you can see, the type of the "SessionImplementor" parameter has been changed.

Comment: I have solved my issue in another way, but as I remember, I have changed that way too and it didn't help either. I will try this for the next opportunity and will let you know about the results. Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: Hey mate, how did you solve the issue? What was the other way you are referring to?

Comment: @Rocky - If this question is still actual for you, check out my answer here.